# Images, music, videos, youtube, flash and vimeo x-browser media player plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, youtube, vimeo

What I'm looking for is to have media player plugin, which will be able to play following media content:

- images
- audios (optional)
- videos (optional)
- youtube embedded videos
- vimeo embedded videos
- flash (when no flash support then image)

Content should be organized in playlist, and I shuold be able to decide what is the length of the frame with image (of course length of the frame with video/audio when autoplayed, is video/audio length itself). Also I need to be able add custom controls to it, and be able to trigger actions (next, prev, play, pause, stop) using javascript/jquery. I would also like to add click-thru links to the frames.

I couldn't find any with uncle Google or in existing questions, so I decided to post new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Open Standard Media (OSM) Player

http://mediafront.org/osmplayer/#.T9dsiStYvEV